# Get Git status from Go from a different directory

Tags: git, go

I need to get a list of modified files from a different directory.

```
func main() {
    log.Println("Starting Site map")
    dir := "/media/my_path/ubuntu/"

    git0 := "git --git-dir=" + dir + ".git --work-tree=" + dir + " status"
    log.Println(git0) //<-- works when pasted in console
    cmd0 := exec.Command("git", git0)
    status0, err := cmd0.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }
    log.Println(status0)

    git := "git --git-dir=" + dir + ".git --work-tree=" + dir
    log.Println(git)
    cmd := exec.Command("git", "status", git)
    status, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(whereami.WhereAmI(), err)
    }
    log.Println(status)
    log.Println("End Site map")
}
```

The I have the following output:

```
2021/05/24 11:38:07 Starting Site map
2021/05/24 11:38:07 git --git-dir=/media/my_path/ubuntu/.git --work-tree=/media/my_path/ubuntu/ status
2021/05/24 11:38:07 File: main.go  Function: main.main Line: 19 exit status 1
2021/05/24 11:38:07 []
2021/05/24 11:38:07 git --git-dir=/media/my_path/ubuntu/.git --work-tree=/media/my_path/ubuntu/
2021/05/24 11:38:07 File: main.go  Function: main.main Line: 28 exit status 128
2021/05/24 11:38:07 []
2021/05/24 11:38:07 End Site map
```

This command: `git --git-dir=/media/my_path/ubuntu/.git --work-tree=/media/my_path/ubuntu/ status`
It works fine when pasted into the console.

The expected result would be array containing modified files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec.Command` takes a command and some arguments.

You’re calling it with ‘git’, then ‘git …’ as an argument, which is executed like

```
git "git --git-dir …"
```

which isn’t going to work.

---

- Don’t repeat the command in the argument.
- Use individual arguments.
- Provide the path to the git command.

Each argument should be a separate string comma separated.

```
exec.Command("/path/to/git", "--git-dir=" + dir + ".git", "--work-tree=" + dir, "status")
```

Comment: See also Steven Perry's answer; setting `cmd.Dir = dir` is shorter and easier (hence more understandable) than providing both `--git-dir` and `--work-tree`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
package main

import (
   "os"
   "os/exec"
)

func main() {
   c := exec.Command("git", "status")
   c.Dir = "/media/my_path/ubuntu"
   c.Stdout = os.Stdout
   c.Run()
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec#Cmd.Dir